# How to compile a simple thread app using Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I have the following BUILD file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts = [
        '-fpic',
        '-pthread'
    ],
)
```

with the following main.cpp:

```
#include <thread>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto a = std::thread([](){});
    return 0;
}
```

The above cpp file compiles with `g++ -pthread`, but fails when compiling in Bazel with the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:122: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
```

Am I passing the flag in a wrong way? what do I need to do in order to have threads when compiling using Bazel?

EDIT:

neither `-pthread` nor `-lpthread` works

Comment: `g++ -lpthread` instead of `g++ -pthread`

Comment: Add `-lpthread` into the the `linkopts` argument, e.g. `... copts = ['-fpic'], linkopts = ['-lpthread'] ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lpthread` needs to be added to the `linkopts` attribute (as King Stone and dms suggested)

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts = [
        "-fpic",
    ],
    linkopts = ["-lpthread"],
)
```

`error: undefined reference` is a linker error. All commands specified at the `linkopts` attribute are handed over to the linker.